# Extracting numbers between bash array strings

Tags: bash, regular-expression

I have a bash array `${a[@]}` which contains files like:

```
List.150.dmg
List.151.dmg
List.152.dmg
....
```

I would like to extract only the numbers in between the digits. Can this be done in GNU grep?

Comment: What does "numbers in between the digits" mean exactly? what is your desired output? if you simply want to remove non-digit characters you may be able to do that during expansion - something like `"${a[@]//[!0-9]}"` or `"${a[@]//[![:digit:]]}"`

Comment: I would like to exactly take out elements between `List` and `.dmg` in case more numbers appear in the future. Is there a way to modify the array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have GNU `basename` and that all names end with `.dmg`:

```
$ basename -s .dmg "${a[@]#*.}"
150
151
152
```

The `"${a[@]#*.}"` expands to each name with the initial bit up to and including the first dot character removed.  The GNU `basename` utility can remove the suffix from a set of filenames given the `-s` option.

The result can be read into a new array, `n`,

```bash
readarray -t n < <(basename -s .dmg "${a[@]#*.}")
```

Since we're using `basename`, this would also work even if the filenames had a directory path specified:

```
$ a=(/some/path/List.{150..153}.dmg)
$ readarray -t n < <(basename -s .dmg "${a[@]#*.}")
$ printf '%s\n' "${n[@]}"
150
151
152
153
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#! /bin/bash

a=(List.150.dmg List.151.dmg List.152.dmg)

for file in "${a[@]}"; do
    number="${file#*.}"
    number="${number%.*}"
    echo "$number"
done
```

Comment: Without the loop: `a=(List.150.dmg List.151.dmg List.152.dmg); number=("${a[@]#*.}") number=("${number[@]%.*}"); echo "${number[@]}"`

Answer (score 2):

Use `cut`:

```
printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}" | cut -d. -f2
```